# How to add multiple values to case sensitive powershell hashtable?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I need a (key,value) hashtable of alphabet to convert letters and numbers to codes in PowerShell, i did it like this:

```
$symbols = @{"A"="0x41"; "B"="0x42"; "C"="0x43"; "D"="0x44"; "E"="0x45"; "F"="0x46"; "G"="0x47"; "H"="0x48"; "I"="0x49"; ....}
```

But then i noticed that hashtables are case insensitive by default, and i need case sensitivity. I found that i can create case sensitive hashtable with:

```
$symbols = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable
```

and then add values:

```
$symbols.Add("a","0x41")
$symbols.Add("A","shift+0x41")
....
```

But that will take 52 lines of code, is there any way to add multiple values to CASE SENSITIVE hashtable in one line?
Because if i try to combine two hashtables or add values in one line, it becomes case INsensitive and throws error about duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this potentially does what you're after:

```
$symbols = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable

 ((65..90) + (97..122)) | ForEach-Object {
    $symbols.Add([char]$_,"$(if ($_ -lt 97) {'shift+'})0x{0:x}" -f $( if ($_ -lt 97) { $_ } Else { $_ -32 }))
}

$symbols.GetEnumerator() | sort name
```

This assumes that you're converting the character to hex code.

Explanation:

- `((65..90) + (97..122))` creates an array of two ranges of numbers, which are the decimal codes for A..Z and a..z.
- Converts the decimal code to it's corresponding character letter with `[Char]`
- If the code is less than 97 add the text `Shift+` to the start of the value.
- Uses `"0x{0:x}" -f <number>` to convert the number to its hex equivalent, changing the range back to the lower case range for the uppercase characters by subtracting 32.

Comment: Wow, this is some advanced stuff. Good idea to use ranges to reduce number of lines. If there's no native way to do this, then yours is the only way, thank you!